# The volume provided is outside the range [0, 1] error

Tags: javascript

I have this code to do Fade In and Out the audio of the video tag each time I execute the code.

```
  var allVideos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
           if (0 < allVideos[0].volume && allVideos[0].volume <= 1){
             fadeOutFunction();
             console.log("Entered first if statment");
}   else if (allVideos[0].volume == 0) {
             fadeInFunction();
};

        function fadeOutFunction() {
         var value = 0.01;
         var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 10);
         function myTimer() {


         if(allVideos[0].volume != 0){
            allVideos[0].volume -= value;
         } else if(allVideos[0].volume == 0){
             clearInterval(myVar);
         }
         }
        }
           function fadeInFunction() {
         var value = 0.01;
         var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 10);
         function myTimer() {
         allVideos[0].volume += value;
         if(allVideos[0].volume == 1){
             clearInterval(myVar);
         }
         }
           }
```

Here is the code:

The code works fine and I can fade out the video. But each time I execute the function I get this error :

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'volume' property on
>   'HTMLMediaElement': The volume provided (-5.30825e-16) is outside the
>   range [0, 1].
>       at myTimer
>
> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'volume' property on
>   'HTMLMediaElement': The volume provided (-3.08781e-16) is outside the
>   range [0, 1].
>       at myTimer

The last one continues to run with my interval too.

Comment: It looks like you're running into some floating point error. I would recommend stopping the interval if `.volume` is less than or equal to 0 not just equal.  With floating points, you typically want to check a range not an exact value to avoid this type of issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dealing with a floating-point arithmetic approximation error.

For instance, `0.03 - 0.01 - 0.01 - 0.01` will give you `-3.469446951953614e-18`.

Replace

```
allVideos[0].volume += value;
```

by

```
allVideos[0].volume = Math.min(1, allVideos[0].volume + value);
```

and

```
allVideos[0].volume -= value;
```

by

```
allVideos[0].volume = Math.max(0, allVideos[0].volume - value);
```

Comment: why I got that I already have ``else if(allVideos[0].volume == 0){
             clearInterval(myVar);
         }``

Comment: I mean I just cleared the interval when ``allVideos[0].volume == 0``

Comment: how is that possible...the number `1.3877787807814457e-16 ` is still greater than `0` so why the compiler is showing the error

Comment: Let's say the current volume is 0.03, if you subtract 0.01 you get 0.01999... and if you subtract 0.01 again you get 0.00999... and by subtracting 0.01 again you get below 0.